# ASP.NET Core 3.1+ Endpoint routing priorities

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I have something like this:

```
endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
endpoints.MapDynamicControllerRoute<SeoTransformer>("{**path}");
```

MapDynamicControllerRoute being called first in all cases. How to change it?

1. Check existing default routes
2. If not found -->  MapDynamicControllerRoute("{**path}")

Comment: Can you post the  SeoTransform code and some controller code? I tested with asp net core 3.1 an looks like the `MapDynamicControllerRoute` call has the lowest priority even if called first

Comment: @Leo the SeoTransformer code has no effect on the result. There is a search for the controller and action in the database by Request.Path

Answer (score 0):

According to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#url-matching), the order of operations inside UseEndpoints doesn't influence the behavior of routing.

In the legacy implementation of routing, it's possible to implement routing extensibility that has a dependency on the order in which routes are processed. Endpoint routing in ASP.NET Core 3.0 and later:

Doesn't have a concept of routes.
Doesn't provide ordering guarantees. All endpoints are processed at once.

So if you want to map controller not found to specific controller, you could try to use MapFallbackToController.

If the url doesn't match other route, it will match this fallbacktocontroller method.

Example:

```
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();

            endpoints.MapFallbackToController("Index", "Fallback");

             });
            
        }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: MapFallbackToController doesn't seem like the best option because my SeoTransformer searches through 500000+ paths that have different controllers and actions. Using redirects seems to be not the best option.

Comment: _"Doesn't provide ordering guarantees. All endpoints are processed at once."_ - What do you mean by this, considering that [`RouteEndpoint` has an `Order` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.routing.routeendpoint.order?view=aspnetcore-7.0), and that [the documentation says routes are ordered by specificivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#rtp)?